# How can I cold smoke without any of the equipment?

Tags: meat, smoking, fire, outdoor-cooking

I need to cold smoke a whole leg of lamb for a few hours. I have a barbecue and plenty of space, but none of the equipment for cold smoking.
What can I do? I'm looking for a quick, simple, one-off solution

Comment: Cold smoking without the proper equipment would be tricky, and can be dangerous if you aren't cooking the meat immediately after. Is there a reason you can't hot smoke over a very low heat (approx 200-225 F or so)?

Comment: It's not that I can't, I just don't want to...I want the effects of cold smoking

Comment: Cold smoking is going to require 'some equipment', on the other hand some of the [equipment can be improvised.](https://www.google.com/search?q=home+made+cold+smoker&oq=home+made+cold+smoker&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5600j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  Several of these videos look promising, but as I have never actually tried any of them I'll not call this 'an answer'.

Answer (score 3):

There are smoke extract products available, such as Liquid Smoke and others with the type of wood smoke flavor desired being specified. With only a few hours to work with, you may wish to inject the solutin to speed up penetration into the meat. Brine or marinade diluents may be options to explore depending on your desired outcome.

Even so, minimal " equipment " such as the injection syringe and a container with some means of covering for the leg would be helpfull, or at least a foil or other wrapping for the 
lamb to keep juice in and atmosphere out.

Comment: Note that these taste differently. Personally, I find several types of smoke flavors used in supermarket meats disgusting.

Comment: I like this answer as a solution to the problem. I was, however, looking for the preservative properties of smoking as well, so won't accept this answer yet.

Comment: It would help to know some of your preferred variables such as how cold and for how many hours you plan to store the meat, which would affect the need for preserving accommodations sans heat. Also, do you plan to eat it as a main entree, normally cooked, or some other way, such as jerky?